# Firebug/Javascript Aborts

Tags: javascript, firebug, greasemonkey, userscripts

I am new to Javascript. I am trying to navigate to a page and "scrape" the screen. I am using Firefox, Greasemonkey and Firebug. I amd trying to use location.href which might be the problem. I want to navigate to a page, parse the contents, use the contents to navigate to other pages. Here is an example (my site is different, but I am getting the same error/result):

```
location.href='http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp';
/* parse and find text */
location.href='http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro';
alert('finished');
```

No matter what I do, Firebug/Greasemonkey just quits after the first location.href. The alert will show, but even if I have a breakpoint set there, it will run right past it. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1: A lot of dynamically generated links (fetched with [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest))**

```
//...
//@include http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp
//@grant   GM_xmlhttpRequest
//...

var urls = [];
//parse text to generate some links on the fly and store them in urls[]
var i = 0, numUrls = urls.length, reportEntries = [], count = 0;
for(; i < numUrls; i++) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: 'GET', 
        url: urls[i], 
        onload: function(response) {
            var returnedHtml = response.responseText;
            //extract more information from returnedHtml and store it in reportEntries[i]
            if(++count >= numUrls) {
                //print reportEntries[] to form a report
                alert('finished');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Note: If you need to save report as a text file to local disk, Greasemonkey is not a viable option as it does not have the privilege to open local files. None the less you can save it to online storage such as pastebin.com.

**Scenario 2: Limited number of static links**

```
//...
//@include  http://some.landing/page
//@include  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp
//@include  http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro
//...
if('http://some.landing/page' == location.href) {
    location.href = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp';
}
else if('http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_examples.asp' == location.href) {
    /* parse and find text */
    location.href='http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro';
}
else if('http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro' == location.href) {
    alert('finished');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response zanetu, but that doesn't work. I need the script to navigate to multiple pages without interaction from the user. This might be closer to what I need, but I still can't get it to do more than one navigation:

Comment: location.href='http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_link';
if('http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_basic_link' == location.href) {
location.href='http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_headers';
if ('http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filenametryhtml_headers' == location.href) {
var sHTML = document.getElementById('script');
alert(sHTML);
alert('finished');
}
}
}

Comment: @Steve Gon
In my answer above, the script is loaded three times, each starting from the very beginning. (Think of going to a hospital multiple times to see a different doctor each time.) If you need to store and retrieve data across page loads, you will need [GM_setValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) and [GM_getValue](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_getValue). Moreover, you'd better revise your question to clarify what you want to do. (e.g. Are you going to insert the text found on one page into another page?)

Comment: Thanks @zanetu for the quick response.
1. How does the script run three times? Do I tell the script somehow to run on a page load?

2. The real objective is to go to page one, read the HTML inner text, generate 10-20 URLs and then navigate to each URL extract more information from those pages and put together in a report.

Comment: @Steve Gon Yes. A Greasemonkey script is loaded each time the current url matches one of its `//@includes`. Answer modified according to your clarification.